# Can't modify my java source file in Netbeans. Source file display in grey window

Tags: java, permissions, netbeans-8

I was writing the code in Netbeans and everything was fine. But Suddenly My computer shutdown. After i open my java source file in Netbeans it doesnot let me edit. The window is gray. For the better clarification i have attached the screenshot below.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUS6y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because somebody (somehow) changed your file permissions to read-only. You can change the 
permission to full control.

**If you are on Windows**
:  `icacls <yourFile> /grant %username%:(r,w,x)`

**if you are in Linux**
: `chmod a+rwx <yourFile>`

or you can recursively do the whole project directory using below command

**If you are on Windows**
 : `icacls * /grant %username%:(OI)(CI)(r,w,x) /T`

Explanation:
F = Full Control
CI = Container Inherit - This flag indicates that subordinate containers will inherit this ACE.
OI = Object Inherit - This flag indicates that subordinate files will inherit the ACE.
/T = Apply recursively to existing files and sub-folders. (OI and CI only apply to new files and sub-folders).

**If you are on Linux**
 : `chmod a+rwx * -R`

//R is recursive**